# How to improve performance in multi-class?

Tags: multiclass-classification, network-traffic

I'm classifying traffic using the CIC-2020 Darknet data set.
There are 8 classes in the data set.
I tried a lot of different ways.  (Over sampling, Under Sampling, Complex Sampling and Outlier Elimination, Feature Selection, model change - cat boost, rus boost, Decision Tree, Random Forest, OvO, OvR, SVM etc..)
However, the performance doesn't improve.
In the picture below, I only selected features using RFECV and used Light GBM.  This has the best performance.

[LightGBM Performance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeodr.png)

Is there a good way to improve performance in multi-class classification?
Please help me.